# DataMapper's many-to-many get all foreign IDs

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

**NEW QUESTION:**

easier test case, create a database

```
CREATE USER test WITH PASSWORD $$test$$;
CREATE DATABASE test;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test TO test;
# add to pg_hba.conf if needed
```

datamapper setup:

```
require 'data_mapper'
DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://test:test@127.0.0.1/test')

class Membership
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :ended_at, DateTime

  belongs_to :user, key: true
  belongs_to :group, key: true
end

class Group
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String

  has n, :memberships
  has n, :users, through: :memberships
end

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String

  has n, :memberships
  has n, :groups, through: :memberships
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_migrate!

u1 = User.create name: 'u1'
u2 = User.create name: 'u2'
g1 = Group.create name: 'g1'
g2 = Group.create name: 'g2'
g3 = Group.create name: 'g3'

u1.groups << g1
u1.groups << g3
u2.groups << g2
g3.users << u2
u1.save
u2.save
g3.save

# User.all = [#<User @id=1 @name="u1">, #<User @id=2 @name="u2">
# Group.all = [#<Group @id=1 @name="g1">, #<Group @id=2 @name="g2">, #<Group @id=3 @name="g3">]
# Membership.all = [#<Membership @id=1 @ended_at=nil @user_id=2 @group_id=2>, #<Membership @id=2 @ended_at=nil @user_id=2 @group_id=3>, #<Membership @id=3 @ended_at=nil @user_id=1 @group_id=1>, #<Membership @id=4 @ended_at=nil @user_id=1 @group_id=3>]
```

how to get all ids of User from all some group, and all ids from Groups from some users?

```
user_ids = [1,2]
User.all(id:user_ids).what???
# desired output: {'1' => [1,3], '2' => [2,3]}   
#   user with ID=1, has two groups (with ID=1 and ID=3)
#   user with ID=2, also has two groups (with ID=2 and ID=3)

group_ids = [1,3]
Group.all(id:group_ids).what???
# desired output: {'1' => [1], '3' => [2,3]} 
#   group with ID=1, has one user (with ID=1)
#   group with ID=3, has two users (with ID=2 and ID=3)
```

**OLD QUESTION:**

for example, if i have 3 tables

```
class Human
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial 
  property :name, String
  has n, :memberships
end

class Group
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial 
  property :name, String
  has n, :memberships
end

class Membership
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :ended_at, DateTime
  belongs_to :human, key: true
  belongs_to :group, key: true
end
```

how to get all Group.id from a Human? or Human.id from a Group? so it would be shown like this:

```
human_ids = [1,3,4]
group_ids = Human.get_all_group_ids??? human_ids
group_ids # { '1' => [3,5,7], '3' => [1,9], '4' => [6,7,9,12] }
```

is it possible to do this in simple way on DataMapper? with the most efficient query as possible?

or should i do manually?

```
sql = "
 SELECT x1.id AS hid, x3.id AS gid
 FROM humans x1
   LEFT JOIN memberships x2
     ON x1.id = x2.human_id
   LEFT JOIN groups x3
     ON x2.group_id = x3.id
 WHERE x1.id IN ( #{human_ids.join ','} )
 ORDER BY 1,2
"

rows = repository(:default).adapter.select sql

res = {}
rows.each do |row|
  hid = row[:hid]
  res[hid] = [] if res[hid].nil?
  res[hid] << row[:gid]
end

# res is the result
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, To get all group ids from Human

```
Group.all(id: memberships(&:group_ids).flatten)
```

Get all human ids from Group

```
Human.all(id: memberships(&:human_ids).flatten)
```

Comment: i don't know why, but it shows: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'memberships' for main:Object`

Comment: the relation is membership or memberships? maybe you should try both.